# What is JSON.parse() and JSON.stringify() Doing in the Code Below. I am Building a Book Library

Tags: javascript, json, oop

```
class Store{


    static getBooks(){
        let books;
        if(localStorage.getItem('books') === null){
             books = [];
        }else{
            books = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('books'));
        }

        return books;
    }

    static addBook(book){
        //get the books form The GetBooks() Function
        const books = Store.getBooks();

        books.push(book);
        localStorage.setItem('books',JSON.stringify('books'));
    }
       
}
```

This is the Code that I have written for storing the books locally. I Was watching a Youtube Tutorial while building it and i don't seem to have got an understanding of what JSON Does

Comment: Read this: [What is JSON anyway](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/JSON)

Comment: You can read up on JSON here: [JSON](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON). In summary: The `JSON.stringify()` method converts a JavaScript object or value to a JSON string and `JSON.parse()` method parses a JSON string, constructing the JavaScript value or object described by the string.

Comment: The setItem is incorrect ... you are stringifying a string not the variable

Comment: As @charlietfl said, a bit more detailed:
You used `localStorage.setItem('books',JSON.stringify('books'))`, where you should have used (guessing by your perceived intent) `localStorage.setItem('books',JSON.stringify(books))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

localStorage can keep data in string format so before you can use it as object data in Javascript you need to turn it in to an object using JSON.parse() method.

when saving it back to the localStorage, you need to turn it back to a string value using JSON.stringify()

Answer (score 0):

`JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('books'))` gets the value of `books` from localStorage (always a string) and *parses* that value into a javascript object.
On the other hand `localStorage.setItem('books',JSON.stringify(books))` turns the object into a string so it can be set inside `localStorage` (you can only put strings in local storage).

Comment: You are correct.
OP made a mistake of `stringify('books')` instead of `stringify(books)`, as @charlietfl pointed out in the comments to the question.
Just pointing it out = not your fault = just missed it as I did until I saw the comment...